# How do I get normal JavaFX text field after changing text field color?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get a normal text field after I changed the color. Salary and Wage is the red text field I change it to. Investment income is my attempt at making it go back to normal and Total income is the text field I would like to get after I changed the color to red.

This is the code I am using for the color change. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
tfTotalPaymentOverLife.textProperty().addListener((ob, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (isNumeric(newValue)) {
            tfTotalPaymentOverLife.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        } else {
            tfTotalPaymentOverLife.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        }
    });
```

[image: Hello]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-fx-control-inner-background` css to paint the inner background of the textfield.

You can set the desired background color to this property or go back to the default color by using `setStyle("")`

Code :

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((ob, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     if (isNumeric(newValue)) {
         textField.setStyle("");
     } else {
         textField.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red");
     }
});
```

Comment: Or just `textField.setStyle("");`, which will revert back to whatever is defined in the user agent stylesheet (i.e. modena). :).

Comment: @James_D This is really useful. Thanks ! :)